# React-native : GoogleSignIt ok but not display in authGmail in Firebase is empty

Tags: react-native, google-signin

I use the method to check the react-native ( react-native-community/google-signin ).

```
import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-community/google-signin';

 // IHM 
     Button
          title="Google Sign-In"
          onPress={() => this._onGoogleButtonPressAndroid()}
       />

 // JS method 
 _onGoogleButtonPressAndroid() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  GoogleSignin.signIn()
    .then( userInfo => {
      const { idToken } = userInfo
      const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Root')
      resolve(true)
    }).catch(err => {
      reject(err)
    })
})
```

}

I click on the button, I see a prompt, I select a gmail.  The redirection is ok

Second step.

I delete the mail in firebase,
I restart my app,
I restart the same process,
I click on the button, I don't see a prompt. The redirection is ok but i don't see the mail ( authentification page ) in firebase.

Firebase SignIn without problem.   It's normal ? My code is not correct ?

Thanks for help

[image: capture of Gmail Auth]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have to add SHA-1 Key to your Firebase project that is needed to Google Sign In and Phone Auth.

Please refere React Native Firebase for how to generate and SHA-1 key add to your project.

https://rnfirebase.io/